# how to add commas before,in between and after the array in php

Tags: php

How should i add the commas before,in between and after the array in php 
here is my code

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

$string = implode(',', $arr);

echo $string;
```

getting output: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

expected output : ,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,

Comment: why not just `echo ',', $string, ','`? implode is not going to magically create invisible array elements for you.

Comment: are you trying to merge this with another list or array? if so ther may be some array functions that can better help your real end goal

Comment: just curious, what situation do you need to do this? It helps us to recognize what problems are trying to be solved. Yes, the answer is trivial - what problem you want that answer for, is interesting to me.

Answer (score 2):

Just concatenate those commas

```
$string = ','.implode(',', $arr).',';
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);
$str = '';
foreach($arr as $ar){
 $str .= "-{$ar}";
};

echo $str.'-';
```